Generate a series of consistent image of one object or environment
I need to achieve this:
I prompt the AI to generate the image of an imaginary place. Then, when I prompt again, I would like images of the same imaginary place, from different angles and/or at different distances.
I’m currently using DALL-E and MidJourney.
Note, I am aware that it’s possible to train a custom Stable Diffusion model to learn a specific object/environment/character, then generate more images of the learnt object/environment/character. However I don’t have any training images to begin with, and I’m trying to rely on the AI to come up with more images from the one that it has just generated.
In MidJourney, I tried copying the seed and attaching it to the end of subsequent prompts, but it doesn’t seem to really impact the results, as the results are still very different from the image that I copied the seed from, as well as between themselves.
DALL-E is currently merged into chatGPT, so I tried verbally instructing it to do so, but it hasn’t been able to do as I instructed.
Please help, thanks!
If you are familiar with Stable Diffusion and know of any workflow that can achieve this (without already having a set of training images) please let me know as well!
